# Django URL Does not Exist?

Tags: python, django

This is very strange, any ideas?: [image]

Here is my code for urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf.urls import include
from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('videos/', include('videos.urls'))
]
```

And videos/urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views


urlpatterns = [
    path(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually, I fixed it! Simple mistake. Change videos\urls.py to this;[image]

Comment: yep, you mixed django 1.11 and django 2.0 url syntax.

Comment: Exactly! I'm traditionally a C/C++ developer, so I'm just getting into web dev over here haha

Comment: you can use re_path instead of path as well